# Web analytics on Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, json, symfony, statistics

I would like to know if there are any bundle to get page analytics, such as active logged in users, anonymous users, current visitors, total visitors etc.

If there aren't, which opensource platform do you recommend me to use into my webpage server, to handle all this data, then retrieving it into my symfony2 with json, rest, or any other utility?

What I want to accomplish here is to use SonataAdminBundle to show into my main page all that statistics I mentioned above, to have an all-in-one system to manage my webpage data such as users, posts, votes, comments, statistics, etc